# .com / .se / de - loading same main folder. htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cross-domain

I have 4 domains, each with a different extension (.com / .de / .se / .no)

I want all domains to load the same main website folder on my server, but depending on the extension the language will change on the site.

The domain names are not the same. eg.

```
ostemad.dk
cheeseflavour.com
fromage.fr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the question here? You do not need any .htaccess style files for this at all. Actually those files should be avoided anyways wherever possible: they considerably slow down the server, are error prone and hard to debug. Use the real server configuration section instead: much more clear and secure.

You just create one virtual hosts per domain and simply assign the same document root to each.

For the language switching you can either rely on phps superglobal variables and switch depending on the request host, or, more elegant, set an environment variable inside the virtual hosts definition by means of apaches mod_setenvif.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a capture group from the last condition with `%1` till `%9`. You can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(dk|com|fr)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=%1 [QSA,L]
```

This selects dk, com and fr from the sitename and appends this to the query. The first condition is just to prevent the rule matching an infinite amount of times.